# iMacros: Script pastes the Text "CONTENT={{!CLIPBOARD}}" rather than the actual Clipboard Content?

Tags: imacros

I am trying to get iMacros for Firefox (v10.0.2) to copy/paste data, the copying side is working (as confirmed by iMacros pop-ups) but when pasting instead of pasting the Clipboard content, it's actually pasting "CONTENT={{!CLIPBOARD}}" (without the quotation marks).

This is my Script...:

```
FRAME F=0
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:resultsdivsml EXTRACT=TXT
TAB T=1
FRAME F=12
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:msku-custom-option-input CONTENT={{!CLIPBOARD}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:msku-custom-option-add
```

My Config Info:

```
iMacros version = 10.0.2.1450
Firefox version = 70.0.1 (64bit)
Win 10 (64bit)
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

[image: Image showing current paste results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good Quality for your Qt, this is pretty "rare" on this Forum for 'iMacros' Qt's... (+1 from me...)

Like mentioned/explained in your parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum:
https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=30705&p=84161#p84154
=> I think you are hitting a Bug actually, but that's not "really" the Functionality that you want...
(The Thread on the iMacros Forum contains more Info, I'm only posting a "simplified"/shortened Answer on this Forum...)

In order to paste the Content of the 'EXTRACT', you need to use the '{{!EXTRACT}}' Command (and not '{{!CLIPBOARD}}' like you are currently doing)...

And if you do several 'C&P' in your Script, you each time need to reset the '!EXTRACT' Built-in Var before each 'EXTRACT':

```
VERSION BUILD=10021450
FRAME F=12
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:msku-attribute-add
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX ATTR=ID:msku-own-parent-tag-checkbox CONTENT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:msku-custom-parent-attribute-input CONTENT=Sticker<SP>Size
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=ID:msku-add-parent-tag-btn
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:msku-custom-option-link

TAB T=2
FRAME F=0
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:resultsdivsml EXTRACT=TXT
TAB T=1
FRAME F=12
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:msku-custom-option-input CONTENT={{!EXTRACT}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:msku-custom-option-add

TAB T=2
FRAME F=0
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:resultsdivstd EXTRACT=TXT
TAB T=1
FRAME F=12
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:msku-custom-option-input CONTENT={{!EXTRACT}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:msku-custom-option-add

... etc...
```

Grrr..., and this Site is Buggy again, the Toolbar with all Formatting Icons (Bold/Italic/Code/etc...) has now kind of disappeared and is just Blank...! (PM v26.3.3) => I have to use a different Browser (FF v55.0.3) to be able to post this Answer...